# Is it possible to find all pages of a website? Like the "unlisted" YouTube links

Tags: web, hyperlink, youtube

I've created a private platform based on the YouTube "unlisted" method. As long as you have the link, everyone can access that content.

But now I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible for someone to find all the pages of my website? Because if that is possible, the whole private thing will just not work.
2. If it is possible, how come no one managed to get the unlisted links from youtube as well? Those are basically pages, after all, right?

These questions are based on the fact that the same way a search engine can display different pages of a website (which can only do if those pages exist), the same way the person who created the search engine can use the same method to just find the unlisted link.

Maybe I am missing something, but this is my base theory and based on that I've asked the above questions. Hopefully, someone can help have a deeper understanding of how "unlisted" links work.